# curly brackets as comment in .inc file

Tags: php

i am having a very weird and i am sure basic problem. There is a .inc file on the server. I need to add php codes into it. I couldnt change the ext to .php since it was being used by other pages. So i did some research and based on that i added this to my .htaccess

```
<Files myfilename.inc>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .inc

</Files>
```

It seems to execute .php codes but there is a problem. I need to use a foreach loop in my code which includes curly brackets. For some reason my notepad(notepad++) shows it as a comment. When i run the code even "echo "1";" doesnt work. Any ideas about that?

My php code:

```
    <div id="install-guides-wrap">
                    <label for="install-guides">Installation Videos</label>
                    <select id="install-guides">
                        <?php

foreach(glob('../files/videos/*.*') as $filename)
{
     $name1 = str_replace('../files/videos/', '', $filename);
     $ext = pathinfo($name1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $notneeded=".".$ext;
     $name = str_replace($notneeded, '', $name1);

     echo "<option value='".$name1."'>".$name."</option>"."<br/>";
     echo "myname";
      echo $name;

 }

            ?>
                        </select>

                    <a class="btn-download" title="Download this file!" href="">DOWNLOAD</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: i just added it there, BTW it works if i just use it in a seperate php file

Comment: Is there anything else in the file?

Comment: Any other php?  can you show your code from the opening php tag?

Comment: there it is, i dont think anything is wrong

Answer (score 0):

While this does not solve the root of your problem, I will bet that the reason that it is being treated like a comment is the `glob('../files/videos/*.*')` (notice how you have a `/*` in there?). While you look for the real cause of the problem, you can work around that by switching it to `glob('../files/videos/'.'*.*')` (That would get rid of the `/*` by breaking it into two parts).

Comment: yes, thats what i thought at first. But unfortunately it doesnt change anyhting. The comments start from "{" and end at "}". I doubt "{ and }" are the comment signs in .inc rather than //